# How to transform a parallelogram image to rectangle image in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Executing cv::warpPerspective for a fake deskewing on a set of cv::Point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838487/executing-cvwarpperspective-for-a-fake-deskewing-on-a-set-of-cvpoint)

I am using OpenCV. I would like to transform an image, which have a parallelogram, to rectangle image. Please tell me how to do ?

Thanks.

Comment: You should try something first instead of "show me the solution". This website is for helping you when you're stuck, not doing the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in the documentation of OpenCV regarding affine transformations. There are examples on there:

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/geometric_image_transformations.html

Answer (score 0):

You want to *shear* the image (or part of it)

For this you could use an affine transform with the [warpAffine function](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/geometric_image_transformations.html#cv-warpaffine)

```
  void warpAffine(const Mat& src, Mat& dst, const Mat& M, Size dsize, 
                  int flags=INTER_LINEAR, int borderMode=BORDER_CONSTANT, 
                  const Scalar& borderValue=Scalar())
```

and read this Q&A: [Performing shear with altered origin in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474706/performing-shear-with-altered-origin-in-opencv)